# SQL Server 2012 Audit for SA and specific accounts

Tags: sql-server, database

Can we setup SQL Server 2012 Audit for specific users? If so, what are the steps to implement Audit trail for the following accounts:

```
1-    SA user
2-3   IT accounts
```

Comment: Have you googled "SQL Server security audit" yet? It's really not that hard.

Comment: hi Nick , i googled   , and i find something like the following link : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/5e788adc-54e5-4e77-8a05-4f6695c66a20/auditing-for-a-specific-loginuser?forum=sqlsecurity   ..... i posted this over stackoverflow if any one for best practice